# angular-ui/ui-select inside a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I am using angular-ui/ui-select inside a custom angular directive, when I first load the page, or do a full browser refresh, the dropdown menu does not appear when I click the dropdown arrow, however, if I navigate to another state (yes I'm using ui-router) then go back to the state that has the dropdown, the dropdown works just fine. Here are a couple of observations:

- I tried to both use prototypal inheritance and an isolated scope for my directive, but in both cases, the erroneous behaviour is present.
- I moved the dropdown outside the directive and it works just fine.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Some code would help... did you inject the dropdown into your directive?

Comment: How do I inject the dropdown into the directive?

Comment: can you make a plunker or fiddle? or at least post some code, without that its difficult to comment on what's going wrong....

Comment: Thanks, I did a Plunker of the problem, but it turns out, that it works perfectly fine over there, there must be some other aspect of my app that is breaking it, will keep on investigating and share the solution, if I find any. In case you curious, this is the Plunker anyway: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zn0EpueI2c7mI7F6VRrK?p=preview